# object' does not contain a definition for 'Range' and no extension method 'Range' accepting a first argument could be found Interop Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Below is the error msg I get when I use the following code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = destworkSheet.get_Range("A2:A16");
Object[,] transposeRange = (Object[,])excelApplication.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng);
transposeRange = excelApplication.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(transposeRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposeRange.GetUpperBound(1));
```

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Range' and no extension method 'Range' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll find you get more helpful answers if you add a little more information to your questions, particularly including the things you have tried to resolve the situation yourself. The error message you have pasted in your question includes two suggestions; have you tried them? I'd strongly recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your question to include some of the things suggested there.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [WorkSheet.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx) property like a method (you are using `( )` parentheses for indexing). If you look into the documentation, you see that the calling convention is to use `[ ]`:

> Excel.Range range1 = vstoWorksheet.Range["C8"];
>       vstoWorksheet.Range["A6", range1].Value2 = "Range 3";

try and change the last line to:

```
excelApplication.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", rng].Resize( .....
```

Comment: Object[,] transposedRange = (Object[,])excelApplication.WorksheetFunction.Transpose("A2:            excelApplication.ActiveSheet.Range["A2"].Resize(transposedRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposedRange.GetUpperBound(1)) = transposedRange;

This is the Error msg I'm getting now
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Automated Browsing.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[,]'.

Comment: what is the range that you want? 2:16 ? like in `rng` ? you probably need to define an additional range like in the example of the documentation